# How to give calculated columns in Angular Material md-data-table with md-order-by

Tags: angularjs, material-design

My column is a calculated column like {{desserts.value1/desserts.value2}}

```
 <md-table-container>
  <table md-table>
    <thead md-head md-order="myOrder">
      <th md-column md-order-by="value1">Dessert (100g serving)</th>
      <th md-column md-order-by="????">Calories</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
      <!-- we can let ng-repeat sort the columns for us -->
      <tr ng-repeat="dessert in desserts | orderBy: myOrder">
        <td>{{ dessert.value1}}</td>
        <td>{{ (dessert.value1 == 0)?0 : dessert.value2)}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</md-table-container>
```

I want to order that column, So what i should give in md-order-by, generally I can give property names.

Comment: Are you using this [module](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) ?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

Answer (score 0):

When I give its value alone without object it will take. ie ((value1==0)?0:value2)

```
<md-table-container>
  <table md-table>
    <thead md-head md-order="myOrder">
      <th md-column md-order-by="value1">Dessert (100g serving)</th>
      <th md-column md-order-by="(value1 == 0)?0 : value2)">Calories</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
      <!-- we can let ng-repeat sort the columns for us -->
      <tr ng-repeat="dessert in desserts | orderBy: myOrder">
        <td>{{ dessert.value1}}</td>
        <td>{{ (dessert.value1 == 0)?0 : dessert.value2)}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</md-table-container>
```